# how handle two triggers to same quartz scheduler

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz scheduler and I have created a trigger for specified time(Every day). And I also created another trigger for another specified time (Every three months once)

Below is my code to schedule two triggers to single scheduler.

```
  Scheduler sch = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MFRScheduler.class)
                .withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();
        JobDetail jobDetail1 = JobBuilder.newJob(MFRScheduler.class)
                .withIdentity("cleanTrigger", "group2").build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("firstJob", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schduledTime))
                    .build();
        Trigger houseKeepingTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("mfrJobHouseKeeping","group2")
                .withSchedule(
                        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cleanTrigerTime)
                        )
                .build();

        sch.start();
        sch.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        sch.scheduleJob(jobDetail1, cleanTrigger);
```

I have overided the method `execute()`  of `org.quartz.Job`

```
   @Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    _log.info("--- This is in Execute method");


    try{



        Thread thread = new Thread(new FIRSTProcess("FIRST_THREAD"),"thread2");
        thread.start();
        thread.setName("FIRST_THREAD");


        thread = null;
        Thread.sleep(3000);


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

What my question is here One trigger triggers every day and content in `execute()` method will execute, since I have only one method `execute()` will get executed for two triggers.

What I need is the content in `execute` method should get executed only when my `firstTrigger` triggers when my second trigger triggers I would like to do some other things instead of making duplicate work of `firstTrigger` 
Can please explain how to segergate the two triggers work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of quartz scheduler do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to do different work, I would suggest to create different implementations of the jobs (e.g. MFRSchedulerHouseKeeping.class). Then you can assign the triggers you want to the specific jobs.

```
Scheduler sch = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MFRScheduler.class)
        .withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();
JobDetail jobDetail1 = JobBuilder.newJob(MFRSchedulerHouseKeeping.class)
        .withIdentity("houseKeepingJob", "group2").build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("firstJob", "group1")
        .withSchedule(
            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schduledTime))
            .build();
Trigger houseKeepingTrigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("mfrJobHouseKeeping","group2")
        .withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cleanTrigerTime)
                )
        .build();

sch.start();
sch.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
sch.scheduleJob(jobDetail1, cleanTrigger);
```

An alternative approach would be to query the Trigger from the `JobExecutionContext` via `getTrigger()` and do the appropriate work on behalf of the result.

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context ) throws JobExecutionException {


    final String triggerName = context.getTrigger().getKey().getName();
    if (TRIGGER_NAME_1.equals(triggerName)) {
         // do work ...
    } 

    // other cases...
}
```

Comment: The second solution I suggested would do that. I added code to clearify it. Although I would go with the class-per-worktype solution. It's the cleaner and more intuitive approach.